# how to pull to refresh on delegate flutter

Tags: flutter

I'm a new Flutter user, so here I want to do a pull to refresh when I'm on the search page, I wonder if you can help me provide a pull to refresh function in the source code that I have provided as follows:

```
floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
          tooltip: 'Search people',
          onPressed: () => showSearch(
                context: context,
                delegate: SearchPage<Nasabah>(
                    onQueryUpdate: (s) => print(s),
                    items: nasabahList,
                    searchLabel: 'Cari Nasabah',
                    suggestion: Center(
                      child: Text('Pencarian berdasarkan nama,alamat,ktp'),
                    ),
                    failure: Center(
                      child: Text('Data tidak ditemukan'),
                    ),
                    filter: (nasabah) => [
                          nasabah.nama_debitur,
                          nasabah.alamat,
                          nasabah.no_ktp.toString(),
                        ],
```

Please help I need you guys, thank you all

Answer (score 0):

You can check the [Flutter Refresh Indicator](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/RefreshIndicator-class.html) widget, I think it will help you achieve the desired behaviour